# Switching ListBox ItemTemplate based on both item type and view option

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplateselector

I'm currently implementing a listbox in WPF that will have 2 alternative layouts for its items:

[image: Alternative list item styles of wrapping icons and detailed tiles]

So far, I've done this using a `DataTrigger` to switch the `ItemTemplate` for the `ListBox` and it's working well:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Runs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRun}">
  <ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource tileTemplate}"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowRunsAsIcons}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource iconTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

However, the `Runs` collection to which the list is bound will also contain different *types* of object:

```
interface IRunItem
{
  // ...
}

class CompletedRunItem : IRunItem
{
  // ...
}

class PendingRunItem : IRunItem
{
  // ...
}
```

Each of the object types should have its own 'tile' and 'icon' templates (making 4 templates in total). What's the best way of switching on these two properties to according to the boolean `ShowRunsAsIcons` and the type of the list item?

I've considered using a pair of `DataTemplateSelector` subclasses -- one to choose between tile templates based on item type, and one to choose between icon templates based on item type -- but this just feels horribly clunky. I feel as though I should be taking advantage of WPF's ability to choose the correct template based on the object's type, but in this instance, I don't see how to combine that with the list's different view options.

Any ideas of how to do this that's more in the spirit of WPF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not convinced it's the best answer, I've changed my approach to take advantage of WPF's automatic template selection. I now have 'top-level' data templates defined for each of my concrete data classes.

These data templates contain nothing but a `ContentControl` whose `ContentTemplate` property is set via a `DataTrigger`, binding to the data context's ShowRunsAsIcons property.

As an example, here's the keyless data template for `PendingRunItem`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Common:PendingRunItem}">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource pendingTileTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ShowRunsAsIcons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource pendingIconTemplate}"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
  </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

The icon and tile representations for the relevant classes are then just regular data templates. And the `ListBox` no longer needs its `Style` property defined:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Runs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRun}"/>
```

I'd be interested to know people's thoughts on this approach and its benefits and drawbacks when compared to using a `DataTemplateSelector` or two.