# How to display a screen with the condition, if 'P' then show 2 columns, else 'R' show 1 column?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a class that has to bind to the screen. In this class it has a type to select if type is 'P' then the screen will show 2 columns (column A and B). But if type is 'R' then screen show 1 column (column A).

I don't know what the element to do this. please help.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleParameters> Collections{get;set;}
    public CollectionType MyType{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: [This][1] can solve my question. 

atomaras, Thank you for your help.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934259/switching-listbox-itemtemplate-based-on-both-item-type-and-view-option

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom converter that returns Visibility.Visible if the value is the type that should show the B column and bind the visibility of the B column using that converter. If you can't solve it using Visibility then you make a converter that returns different DataTemplates depending on the type (one with one column and one with two) and then do this

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding MyType, Converter={StaticResource TypeToTemplateConverter}}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It has been a long time that I asked this question. I just tried it. But i found the above comment can solve it.